# HTML:How to make an html NON CACHE in browsers

Tags: javascript, html, xml, caching

I have an HTML page which renders an XML file and displays in the screen. Every visit of this screen should get the latest XML file and display.
Due to Browser cache, it is unable to display the latest XML file until Clearing the cache.
I tried to stop HTML cache by using following code.

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
```

But the XML file is coming old one only.
Please help me in rendering the latest XML file always on every visit.

Comment: I never found the `<META>` command very reliable. Look at configuring the caching directly on your server with .htaccess or whatever the IIS equivalent is.

Comment: `Meta` tags can only affect the caching of the HTML document itself (at most).

Answer (score 1):

I'd rely on web server HTTP headers instead of meta tags to control caching at the client and proxy levels.

If you're using IIS, you can check out http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770661(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved by adding dummy param to the XML link as follows and it worked for me.

```
var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*1001);
strRefactorUrl   = strRefactorUrl + "?dummy="+randomnumber;
```